# How do you export documentation in JSON format in Flutter?

Tags: json, flutter

How do you export documentation in JSON format in Flutter?

I am developing a chat app using Flutter Flow. I would like to export documents created within the "message" collection where the "from" field name is "AAA" in JSON format.

As a beginner in app development, I haven't been able to try anything at the moment.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. - see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) . As you're new, please take the [tour] and read [ask] too, to understand how to get the best out of Stackoverflow.